# Infinite Re-render even with the use of useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, rerender

I am trying to create an authorized user checker with React, however, my component keeps on re-rendering.

**Here's my approach:**

I created an **authBreaker** state so that my useEffect will update every time it changes and not the **auth** state which is being updated inside the useEffect.

However, it still keeps on re-rendering even though **authBreaker** is not updated.

I also, tried removing the dependencies of my useEffect using [] But it resulted to the same behavior.

```
const Login = React.memo(() => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const [authBreaker, setAuthBreaker] = useState(false)
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false)

  const isAuthorized = () => {
    const user = Cookies.get('token')
    user && setAuth(true)
    console.log(auth)
  }

  const login = async () => {
    try {

      //server code here...
      //if login successful..
      setAuthBreaker(true)

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     isAuthorized()
  }, [authBreaker])

  return (
    <div className="pml-form">
      { auth && <Redirect to="/"/> }
      //code here...
    </div>
  )
})
```

Any idea why it keeps on re-rendering? Thanks!

Comment: Seems there might be a loop between setting the `auth` state true and redirecting... if you are somehow already on the "/" the effect may be running again. Or maybe you are getting bounced back to a route that renders this component? Either way, seems this component is getting remounted and causing the loop. Can you provide a more complete code/app example?

Comment: You can try making a breakpoint on the function body to trace where all the rerenders come from, or use react devtool's profiler, that will give you some hint.

Comment: How is `login` called